# BibLaTeX: how to reverse order of volume and series?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm having trouble where volume is somehow appearing before series, possibly due to my own error. That is, I have

> [1] Da Prato, G., Zabczyk, J. (2014). *Stochastic Equations in Infinite Dimensions*. Vol. 152. Encyclopedia of Mathematics and its Applications. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press.

when I would really rather

> [1] Da Prato, G., Zabczyk, J. (2014). *Stochastic Equations in Infinite Dimensions*. Encyclopedia of Mathematics and its Applications,  Vol. 152., Cambridge: Cambridge University Press.

where the volume number 152 somehow appears before the series (Encyclopedia of Mathematics and its Applications). How can I reverse the order?

The MWE below is a hodgepodge of things I found on this site. Its the smallest I can comfortably make it, I'm not sure if it is truly the most minimal of MWEs. In particular, after removing everything after `\makeatother`, volume is still before series. I thought I should include the rest of it anyway in case I dont realise something interacts weirdly.

The reference:

```
@book{da2014stochastic,
  title={Stochastic Equations in Infinite Dimensions},
  author={Da Prato, Giuseppe and Zabczyk, Jerzy},
  series = {Encyclopedia of Mathematics and its Applications},
  volume = {152},
  year={2014},
  location={Cambridge},
  publisher={Cambridge University Press}
}
```

and my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}

%% BibLaTeX implementation of TandF references style

\usepackage[
    %sorting=none,
    citestyle=numeric,
    bibstyle=authoryear,
    dashed=false,
    firstinits=true
     ]{biblatex}
\makeatletter
\input{numeric.bbx}
\makeatother

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
%  \setunit*{\adddot}% DELETED
  \setunit*{\addnbthinspace}% NEW (optional); there's also \addnbspace
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}% 
  \printfield{eid}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}         

\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon\space}{\addcomma\space}}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\addspace}%
}

\addbibresource[]{bibliography-2.bib}

%%


\begin{document}

test \cite{da2014stochastic}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: The part of a `series` is a `number` and not `volume`.

Comment: @moewe oh, so the code is working 'as intended' and it is my `@book...` that is wrong?

Comment: I should think so, yes.

Comment: Hello @CalvinKhor: you could add this [link](https://archive.ph/2unNE) to your recent nice answer in mse.meta. *The* notorious user was exposed in one of the answers there. See Martin Argerami's comments. In case you are curious, I am one who knows lots of dirty things of mse. I'm sure you know quite a few too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The instalments of a `series` are numbered in the `number` field and not with `volume`. So you want

```
@book{da2014stochastic,
  title     = {Stochastic Equations in Infinite Dimensions},
  author    = {Da Prato, Giuseppe and Zabczyk, Jerzy},
  series    = {Encyclopedia of Mathematics and its Applications},
  number    = {152},
  year      = {2014},
  location  = {Cambridge},
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press}
}
```

[image]