# Whether to use `number` or `volume` in the bib file for a book numbered in a series?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex

If I want to add the numbering for a book in a series, which field should be used? `number` or `volume`?

In `texdoc bibtex`, it says

> **number** The number of a journal, magazine, technical report, or of a work in a series.
>
> **volume** The volume of a journal or multivolume book.

In `texdoc biblatex`, it says

> **number** The number of a journal or the volume/number of a book in a series.
>
> **volume** The volume of a multi-volume book or a periodical.

It seems that both bibtex and biblatex recommend using the field `number` for the designation of a book in the book series.
But usually these two fields will be formatted as "No. xx" and "Vol. xx` for book entries.

Now I am confused, which one should I use in general?
Or there is no general choice and it depends on the style in use?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/514894/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/457598/35864 (and possibly https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/411516/35864)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They mean different things. The `volume` field is for a multi-volume book with a single title and author/editor. The `number` field is for a series of independent books that are published as part of a series.  For example, Don Knuth's *Art of Computer Programming* is a single work with multiple volumes. You would use `volume` for these. But this work itself is part of the Addison-Wesley Professional Computing series. If they number each book in the series, you would use `number` for that number.

As a general rule of thumb, the `number` field for a book in a series is rarely needed, since the book is easily identified from the title, author and publisher. The fact that it's number X in a publisher's series is basically irrelevant. But the volume number of a multi-volume work is very important, since the book usually has a single title and author/editor, so which volume you are citing matters.

Answer (score 6):

I don’t know about `bibtex`, but for `biblatex` you should use `number`.

Here is a specific example:
As part of the series *London Mathematical Society Student Texts*, there are the following three books:

- Elements of the Representation Theory of Associative Algebras, Volume 1: Techniques of Representation Theory
- Elements of the Representation Theory of Associative Algebras, Volume 2: Tubes and Concealed Algebras of Euclidean type
- Elements of the Representation Theory of Associative Algebras, Volume 3: Representation-infinite Tilted Algebras

These are number 65, 71, 72 in the the overall series. An entry for the first volume could look somewhat like this:

```
@book{assem_simon_skowronski_elements_rep_theo_1,
  author    = {Assem, Ibrahim and Simson, Daniel and Skowroński, Andrzej},
  maintitle = {Elements of the Representation Theory of Associative Algebras},
  volume    = {1},
  title     = {Techniques of Representation Theory},
  year      = {2006},
  pagetotal = {x+458},
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
  location  = {Cambridge},
  series    = {London Mathematical Society Student Texts},
  number    = {65},
  isbn      = {978-0-521-58423-4},
  doi       = {10.1017/CBO9780511614309},
}
```

For me, the output of this entry looks roughly as follows.

[image: 1]

Comment: I hesitate for a few days and I am sorry for not choosing your answer as the accepted one. Your answer and the detailed example is very helpful, but Alan Munn gives further advice on the importance of `volume` field for a multi-volume work, though he did not make his example as detailed as yours and your example also indicates his advice. I hope this will not discourage you from answering questions. Again, your answer is very helpful.

Comment: No problem. :-)